# What does the ' ; ' symbol mean in python?

Tags: python, symbols

I sometimes see this ; symbol on tutorials and such, what does it indicate?

Comment: Can you quote any tutorial here?

Comment: Actually, nothing. Its just for Java players :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semi-colons are used in Python to separate statements in the same line.

```
print 1; print 2
```

Common use example:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: And sometimes they are just remnants of code conversion between Python and languages which use the semicolons as line delimiter like C++, Java, etc.

Comment: Okay, just another follow up question, what if I am writing a really large dictionary, and I don't want all the keys to be on the same line because it makes it hard to read over, is there someway that I can denote that is continues to the next line?

Comment: @A-P , use a new line after the comma on each value.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon can be used as a statement separator in Python, called [stmt_list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements) in the language reference, but its use is generally discouraged ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), compound statements). We prefer one statement per line.